# UWP XAML Textbox font color wont change

Tags: xaml, uwp

Maybe I'm missing something here... but the text input of my textbox is always black. I thought you only had to change the Foreground property and the text color would change.

Here is my TextBox. What else do I have to do to make the font blue in this example? There is also a IsColorFontEnabled Property... but that doesn't change anything.

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
         FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"
         Foreground="Blue" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this case Foreground property works only if the TextBox is out of the focus, give it fixed Width and Height, put some text inside and when you click outside the box the colour will change to blue

how to change it on the focused state?
get a default TextBox style:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

copy and paste it into your control's resources, name it with x:Key and then apply to the TextBox. Everything should look the same for now. Find a Focused state
() and change it so you have:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
```

or if you want to inherit it and have the same value for both Focused and Unfocused states:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

after all it can look like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TestStyle">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                              Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontStyle="Normal"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Text="&#xE10A;"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
            Grid.Row="1"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                      x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,8"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                      FontWeight="Normal" />
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                  ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  IsTabStop="False"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
            IsTabStop="False"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
            MinWidth="34"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}" Width="100" Height="100"
     FontSize="12" Foreground="Blue"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping I wasn't going to have to override the styles of the TextBox just to do this.

Comment: What the hell? O.o Am I seeing this right? To change the focused color, I have to create a whole new template? This is madness!